# Create drag and drop ,also re order divs with interact js using useref in react

Tags: react-hooks, getboundingclientrect, interactjs

i have a div of icons which are placed side by side using mapping array , i need to drag and drop each icon so that other icons re order itself

was expecting to use refs for position and getBoundingClientRect()

how to implement it without onclick

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.